# Suspended license impact on UK visa already granted

Tags: visa, uk-visa, australian-citizens

My driver's licence was suspended for 3 months in Australia after accruing more than 12 points for various minor speeding offences.

My UK visa has already been approved and processed, in which I answered no to the question whether you had a suspended license (as, at the time of visa application, I hadn't). Now I have a suspended license for 3 months however I'm not sure if it is classified as a criminal offence as it was not for drink driving or any other major offence.

However now my answer would be yes it has been suspended but not from a drinking or drug related offence. Will this affect my visa?

Comment: As you note that you had speeding offenses, how did you respond to the question whether you had received any penalty by a court or the police, e.g., caution, discharge, fine, as this suggests that those are what led to the suspension, and occurred prior to your application. Non-disclosure of those, which might not affect the current visa, may have an impact on future applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89631/do-traffic-offences-have-to-be-included-on-the-uk-visitor-visa-application